# Updating image issue with php using form

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an issue with my php form when i try and update the image which i hope someone can help with.

The form submits the updated fields to the database, however the image upload function which saves the image path to the db and moves the image has a problem when i update.

When i try edit/update the image, all records in my table get overwritten with the same data and no image is saved.

This is the update script i wrote:

```
<?php

//include database connection

include 'includes/db_connect.php';

//check any user action

$action = isset( $_POST['action'] ) ? $_POST['action'] : "";

if($action == "update"){ //if the user hit the update button

//This is the directory where images will be saved 
$target = "images/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['profileimage']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profileimage']['tmp_name'], $target);

    //write our update query

$query = "update models
set
name = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."',
artisttype = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['artisttype'])."',
residence = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['residence'])."',
agerange = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['agerange'])."',
complexion = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['complexion'])."',
enthnicity = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['enthnicity'])."',
haircolor = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['haircolor'])."',
hairlength = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['hairlength'])."',
eyecolor = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['eyecolor'])."',
height = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['height'])."',
weight = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['weight'])."',
bustsize = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['bustsize'])."',
waistsize = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['waistsize'])."',
hipsize = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['hipsize'])."',
shoesize = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['shoesize'])."',
insideleg = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['insideleg'])."',
outsideleg = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['outsideleg'])."',
dresssize = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['dresssize'])."',
profileimage = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_FILES['profileimage']['name'])."',
brasize = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['brasize'])."'
WHERE id='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id'])."'";


//execute the query

if( $mysqli->query($query) ) {

//if updating the record was successful

echo "User was updated.";

}else{

//if unable to update new record

 echo "Database Error: Unable to update record.";

}

}
```

Any tips on where im going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: you should test with print_r($_FILES); to check if $_FILES is set or not.

Comment: is this same form for insert and edit/update?

Answer (score 0):

If your action is `update` and user is not updating the image only updates the information in that case you have to check `$_FILES` if empty then don't update the image field if user select new image then update the image field like

```
//write our update query

$query = "update models
set
name = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."',
artisttype = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['artisttype'])."',
residence = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['residence'])."',
agerange = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['agerange'])."',
complexion = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['complexion'])."',
enthnicity = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['enthnicity'])."',
haircolor = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['haircolor'])."',
hairlength = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['hairlength'])."',
eyecolor = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['eyecolor'])."',
height = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['height'])."',
weight = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['weight'])."',
bustsize = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['bustsize'])."',
waistsize = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['waistsize'])."',
hipsize = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['hipsize'])."',
shoesize = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['shoesize'])."',
insideleg = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['insideleg'])."',
outsideleg = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['outsideleg'])."',
dresssize = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['dresssize'])."',    
brasize = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['brasize'])."' ";

if(!empty($_FILES['profileimage'])){
 $target = "images/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['profileimage']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profileimage']['tmp_name'], $target);
$query.=",profileimage = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_FILES['profileimage']['name'])."'";
}

$query.=" WHERE id='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id'])."'";
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "update models
set
name = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."',
artisttype = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['artisttype'])."',
residence = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['residence'])."',
agerange = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['agerange'])."',
complexion = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['complexion'])."',
enthnicity = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['enthnicity'])."',
haircolor = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['haircolor'])."',
hairlength = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['hairlength'])."',
eyecolor = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['eyecolor'])."',
height = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['height'])."',
weight = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['weight'])."',
bustsize = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['bustsize'])."',
waistsize = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['waistsize'])."',
hipsize = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['hipsize'])."',
shoesize = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['shoesize'])."',
insideleg = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['insideleg'])."',
outsideleg = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['outsideleg'])."',
dresssize = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['dresssize'])."',    
brasize = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['brasize'])."' ";

if(!empty($_FILES['profileimage'])){
 $target = "images/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['profileimage']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profileimage']['tmp_name'], $target);
$query.=",profileimage = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_FILES['profileimage']['name'])."'";
}

$query.=" WHERE id='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id'])."'";

please use $_POST['id']. save id value in hidden field and use id from $_POST['id'];
```